# Why must the asterisk come first?

Tags: mysql, syntax

In MySQL, `select *,1 from t` appears to be valid, but `select 1,* from t` is not.

1. Why is that?
2. Is there any official documentation on this? I can't find anything that says the latter is invalid, and the error message I get doesn't say anything specifically about it either.

Comment: I can't think of any real reason for that, other than it made life slightly easier for the implementers. MS SQL Server has no such limitation (e.g. `select 1,*,2,*,3 from table` works just fine).

Answer (score 4):

[From the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), you are told what you **can** do with the unqualified `*`:

> A select list consisting only of a single unqualified `*` can be used as shorthand to select all columns from all tables:
>
> `SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ...`

The pertinent documentation you're looking for is two bullet points below that:

> Use of an unqualified `*` with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified `tbl_name.*` reference

Unfortunately the *why* is not explained in the docs, and would likely take some digging.

Comment: Interesting. It says it may produce an error, but not under what conditions it will produce an error.

Comment: @Mark That's what I'm curious of - and since I'm curious, I'm cracking open the source tree to peek around. Maybe there's a gold-mine of comments explaining why or what the parsing method is.