# MySQL SELECT col, * FROM table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering why this query returns error:

```
SELECT column_name, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near* '*
>   *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' at line 1*

And other variations are working properly:

```
SELECT column_name, c.*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c;

SELECT *, column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;

SELECT c.*, column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo - MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27f8925e60707ed9519ee1a6eda1e5f9)**

**[db<>fiddle demo - PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=27f8925e60707ed9519ee1a6eda1e5f9)**

**[db<>fiddle demo - SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=27f8925e60707ed9519ee1a6eda1e5f9)**

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please do, I really want to know the answer for that riddle :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617112/why-must-the-asterisk-come-first

Comment: @WelderLourenço But maybe someone reading this question now can explain why this is the case :-)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Yeah...but that duplicate still doesn't explain it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I agree. Maybe someone will have more verbose answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicate link is basically the same question being asked here, for MySQL only.  It does not provide an explanation for why `SELECT *, col1` is allowed and `SELECT col1, *` is not.  I was curious, and setup the following [demo in MySQL 8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=234dc6640479df50c4996a96ae90996e):

```
WITH tb1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
),
tbl2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
)

SELECT tbl1.id, *
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2
    ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id;
```

Look closely, I incorrectly refer to the first CTE as `tbl1` in the query, when in fact is called `tb1`.  It doesn't even get this far, and instead generates the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*

When I fix the CTE and query names to match, then I get the same error.  In other words, the query is failing at the parsing step of the `SELECT` clause, and never even gets as far as worrying about table names, or to what the `*`  is referring.

I am posting this answer because it adds information about how MySQL's parser is handling this case.  The `SELECT col1, *` syntax is not failing because of any ambiguity in `*`, which makes sense because `SELECT *, col1` works.  Instead, it just seems that the parsing rules don't like this syntax, for whatever reason.

Comment: I really like that case. Good clue!

Comment: It seems to be dying very early on, I'll bet you could break any other part of the query and get the same error message.  As to _why_, I could only speculate.  I tried looking this up in the ANSI-92 standard, but came up empty `:-(`

Comment: *" I tried looking this up in the ANSI-92 standard, but came up empty"* the ANSI SQL 92 does mention sequence order when asterisk is used..  `7.9  <query specification> -> Syntax rules`.. But it indeed does not explain why MySQL errors on `SELECT col, * ..`

Answer (score 1):

Some databases treat `select *` as a single construct, in the same way that `select distinct` is a single construct (the `distinct` is not really separate).

This affects how it is parsed.  MySQL clearly has strange rules for this.

In Oracle, for instance, you cannot add additional expressions at all to `select *`.

The simple solution is to use qualified references and table aliases:

```
SELECT c.column_name, c.*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c;
```

Because I always use qualified column references and table aliases, a don't encounter this problem.  Well, actually, I do slip sometimes.  So, I know that Oracle has this particular behavior.

Comment: It  does not explain why: `SELECT *, column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;` does not return error: Oracle would end up with error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return only column_name but also everything. So in the other examples you are return either everything first so column_name is already returned, or you are returning everything within a subset so it's happy:) You may want to do some reading on the * operator in SQL

Comment: This answer is obviosly not correct: [counterexample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0b621806f50a2ad997c52ec0ee5ba1a) with expression